# How to run php file with HTML file to check if the webpage can successfully send emails to someone

Tags: php, html, xampp

I'm trying to create a contact page for my portfolio, where the user could place in their email, subject, and their message and then click a button to send it. I already downloaded XAMPP and PHP and I have been checking the website on the localhost. However, every time I type in the necessary fields and send, it would open up my computers email app and place text into the message field. I don't want this - i'm trying to make the email send from the webpage.

Here is the code for my PHP file:

```
   <?php
$subject = $_Post['subject'];
$visitor_email = $_Post['email'];
$message = $_Post['message'];

$email_body = $message;

$to = "randemail@gmail.com";
$headers= "From: $visitor_email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:$visitor_email\r\n";
mail($to, $subject,$message,$headers);
header("Location:index.html");
?>
```

here is the code to my contact page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game Design Projects | My Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,300;1,200;1,400;1,700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "MainBody">
    <div class="contactmeborder">
        <div class="PortObjname">
            <h2>Reach Out</h2>
        </div>
        <form action="mailto:randemail@gmail.com" method="post" action = "PHP/contact-form-handler.php">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Email"><br>
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder=" Subject"><br>
            <textarea type="text" name="message"  placeholder="Your Message"></textarea> <br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Footer">
    <p class="footinfo">footer</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The PHP/contact-form-handler.php holds what you see for the PHP part of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form action="mailto:randemail@gmail.com"` , action need to be the `php_send_mail.php`

It's open your mail client because that is the current settings. (`mailto...`)

Note: apparently you added twice `action` (just keep the proper one)

`<form action="mailto:randemail@gmail.com" method="post" action = "PHP/contact-form-handler.php">`

Comment: is it correct to use `mailto` in `action="mailto:randemail@gmail.com"`

Comment: This was the case. Thank you for that. I removed the first mailto and now everything works perfectly. Had to change to phpmailer though, but, in the end, this helped me advance.

Answer (score 2):

The form action is using `mailto:`, but it should be pointed to the URL for your PHP script.

`mailto:` is for links on your site so that users can send emails a specific address.

I would also look into using an API service like SendGrid, MailGun, etc. to send emails instead of mail(). PHP's mail() function is very unreliable.